# Change default remote for git-tfs repository

Tags: git, git-tfs

I am working against the customer's on premises TFS server using the git-tfs bridge. Yesterday they migrated their installation to a new version + changed the URL of the server, migrating all the history and the work items to a new instance.

Is there a way to remap my existing git repository to the new default remote?

I tried to manually edit the *url* property of the *[tfs-remote "default"]* so it points to the new address and run every possible `cleanup*` command. However, on a *fetch* attempt there is a bootstrapping process adding a new *tfs-remote* with the old URL to the config file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got 2 solutions:

- The [first](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/specify-alternate-tfs-urls.md), which should be the easier. But, because git-tfs has evolved a lot since it was implemented, I don't know if it still work even if it should...
- Second, that will work for sure, is to update the metadata of the commit corresponding to last changeset fetched from the old TFS. It is used by git-tfs to bootstrap the new tfs-remote when none is found in the `gitconfig` file.

1. Amend the git commit and replace the url in the metadata (something looking like that: `git-tfs-id: [https://tfs.codeplex.com:443/tfs/TFS16]$/vtccds/trunk;C26497` ) to point to the new TFS.
2. Create a backup of your original `.git/config` file:

   ```
    cp .git/config .git/config.bak
   ```
3. Remove all the `[tfs-remote]` settings in the `.git/config` file.
4. Just do a normal `git tfs fetch` from the command line.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Philippe, the second option worked like a charm!

Comment: This saved me days, if not weeks, of headaches. Hope you don't mind, but I edited your answer to give a little more clarity. It took me an afternoon to figure you needed to remove all `[tfs-remote]` entries in `.git/config` and then just do a `git tfs fetch` after amending the last commit.

Comment: @GregBurghardt That's perfectly fine, that's the goal of stackoverflxow. Pleased it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Philippe for his answer... I would add that if you work with sever branches you need to update the config entry for each branch and add a

```
legacy-urls = http://old-url:8080/tfs/Projects
```

for each one, like

```
[tfs-remote "Project/branch/..."]
    url = http://newurl:8080/tfs/Projects
    repository = ....
    legacy-urls = http://old-url:8080/tfs/Projects
```

This will allow git-tfs to accept the checkin of these branches.